# Foobar 2000 change tracks title

Tags: audio, foobar2000

I need to change my audiobook track titles. In new titles I need to have some constant name and variable track number. Is it possible to solve this in foobar? If yeas then how? If no then it there are any tools to fix it?

```
Situation now:
Track   Title
1       blablabla 11
2       blablabla 12
3       blablabla 13

Need to be:
Track   Title
1       bla 01
2       bla 02
3       bla 03
```

Comment: This is possible with foobar, but some more infos are needed. Make a small example list how the values look now and how they should look after your desired change

Comment: I have updated my post with sample

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Foobar2000 has a [rename tool](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000redirect:3BE9DFE2-8960-42C5-87F8-6A3112CC3D3E) already build in. It's a little bit hidden and unknown therefore.

1. Select your files you want to rename and select Properties in the context menu

   [image]
2. Go to `Tools » Automatically fill values...`

   [image]
3. Select `other` as source type and enter `blabla %tracknumber%`, your fixed string and the corresponding tracknumber.

   Everything wrapped with percent signs are variables. Other common variables are %title%,
   %artist%, %album% or %filename%.

   As last step you have to define the MP3 meta tags to change. In your case you want to  change %title%

   [image]
4. Your result: All titles are renamed with a fixed pattern and the tracknumber

   [image]

---

Or use Foobar's plugin [masstagger](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000redirect:5EC79881-4BB0-44DB-8825-50A57E3621DE) which is similar to use, but more powerful since it can use [Foobar's Title Formatting](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference)

[image]