# Foobar how to change metadata

Tags: metadata, foobar2000

I just downloaded foobar and it looks amazing. I have nevertheless a small problem.

When I right click wherever, I'm going inside the options of the whole panel (meaning the UI?) like here :

[image]

that's troublesome because I wanted to change the metadata of my tracks. How can I do that ? I wanted to follow the instruction from there : [Foobar 2000 change tracks title](https://superuser.com/questions/634086/foobar-2000-change-tracks-title/634410#634410)
and there : [How to bulk rename audio files so that the file name matches the title metadata (preferably using Foobar2000)?](https://superuser.com/questions/757411/how-to-bulk-rename-audio-files-so-that-the-file-name-matches-the-title-metadata)

Comment: I have another problem, I can't order the tracks on the panel of the right in the order that I want. It is necessarly in the alphabetical order... how can I change that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on a file or drag select a large number of file and do

Alt + Enter

Now a new editable window will open with all the metadata for those files.

Better still, foobar has a lot of plugins that you can install to help with metadata editing. Go to

https://www.foobar2000.org/components

and check.

Answer (score 1):

Just use double click (left mouse click to be more correct) to word "Metadata" and foobar will open a some scratchbox, where you can to edit metadata of your tracks.

P.S I'm sorry for my bad english. I'm just some randome guy from Russia.