# Automatically retrieve ID3 track name from certain part of filename

Tags: mp3, foobar2000, id3

I have a lot of live mp3 files which are untagged. I can put them in Foobar2000 for automatic track numbers which isn't the issue. This is my Windows Explorer view:

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way with Foobar2000 to change track names.
For example from `20050405_U2_LA1_04 Vertigo` to `Vertigo`.

Answer (score 0):

### Taken from an [older answer](https://superuser.com/a/634410/50173)

1. Right click your files you want to rename and select `Properties` in the context menu
2. Go to `Tools » Automatically fill values...`
3. Select `Other...` as Source and enter `$trim($substr(%filename%,$strchr(%filename%, ),999))`
4. Set `Pattern` to `%Title%` and click OK

   [image]

---

### How the formula works

1. [`%filename%`](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference#.24filename.28x.29) returns the filename. `20050405_U2_LA1_04 Vertigo` in our example
2. [`$strchr(%filename%, )`](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference#.24strchr.28s.2Cc.29) finds first occurrence of a character in a string. In our example it searches for the first space and returns `20` as its position
3. [`$substr(%filename%, 20, 999)`](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference#.24substr.28s.2Cm.2Cn.29) returns a substring of a string, starting at position `20` (taken from example) and ending at `999` (should be long enough to cover all cases). Our example would return `Vertigo` with a leading space
4. [`$trim( Vertigo)`](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference#.24trim.28s.29) removes the leading space